# Cannot retrieve column using eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query that extracts student marks, but I want to also extract the name and surname of the student but I get the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'shunifu_db.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `name`, marks.student_id,ROUND(AVG(mark)) as mark from `grades` inner join `grades_students` on `grades_students`.`grade_id` = `grades`.`id` inner join `users` on `grades_students`.`student_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `marks` on `marks`.`student_id` = `grades_students`.`student_id` where `grades`.`stream_id` = 5 and `assessement_id` = 1 group by `marks`.`student_id`)

here is my code

```
$result = DB::table('grades')
    ->join('grades_students', 'grades_students.grade_id', '=', 'grades.id')
    ->join('users','grades_students.student_id','=','users.id')
    ->join('marks','marks.student_id','=','grades_students.student_id')
    ->where('grades.stream_id', $request->stream_name)
    ->where('assessement_id',$request->assessement)
    ->select(DB::raw('marks.student_id,ROUND(AVG(mark)) as mark'))
    ->groupBy('marks.student_id')
    ->get()
```

Comment: add more detail and also complete your code

Comment: @Shahrukh I have just updated the code

Comment: in which table you are saving student name?

Comment: @Shahrukh, In the Users table

Comment: if you are using group by , you have to select specific columns where you are selecting all column. Use select in query to select specific columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it will work

```
$result = DB::table('grades')
    ->join('grades_students', 'grades_students.grade_id', '=', 'grades.id')
    ->join('users','grades_students.student_id','=','users.id')
    ->join('marks','marks.student_id','=','grades_students.student_id')
    ->where('grades.stream_id', $request->stream_name)
    ->where('assessement_id',$request->assessement)
    ->select(DB::raw('users.id,users.name,ROUND(AVG(mark)) as mark'))
    ->groupBy(['users.id', 'users.name'])
    ->get()
```

Here I'm using user table for grouping and also fetching name.

Comment: which model is assessment_id belongs to? do you have models relationships? (user->grades->marks and mark->grade and grade->user etc.)